# Random org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException in old elasticsearch(1.X) using the Jest client

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, connect-timeout, elasticsearch-1.7.5

I am using very old Elasticsearch 1.x I know its EOL but no choice here and as that time official ES client was not there, using `Jest` client to interact with Elasticsearch and occassionaly seeing the timeout exception when Jest is trying to establish a connection and below is the stack trace of the log

```
rg.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to <es-ip>:9200 [/<es-ip>] failed: connect timed out
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:151)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:374)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
    at io.searchbox.client.http.JestHttpClient.executeRequest(JestHttpClient.java:109)
    at io.searchbox.client.http.JestHttpClient.execute(JestHttpClient.java:56)
```

One weird thing I noticed is that this mostly happen to the Elasticsearch instances hosted in AWS and not in the data centre, I am using Data dog integration with Elasticsearch for elasticsearch infra monitoring and can provide more relevant details if required from there.

Comment: Any news on this investigation? Is It behind a elb? I am having a similiar situation with webservices behind elb

Comment: Nope  I am still looking for answer and yes its behind a elb and have same setup as you have.